# How can I find if key exists in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I want to write a program in python that finds a value in list.
Something like this:

```
arr = [1, 14, 2, 4, 5, 11, 8, 10]
for i in range(1, len(arr)):
    if(i * 2 in arr):
        print "!"
```

The array I want to check is way way longer so it takes really long time.
i came up with an idea to make a hash table instead of a list.
someting like this:

```
arr = {1: "something", 14: "something", 2: "something", 4: "something",
       5: "something", 11: "something", 8: "something", 10: "something"}
```

My idea was to check if `i` for example equal to `2` so to check if `arr[i*2]` will return something because this way the program won't need to find something just to call it if it exists.

The problem is if `i` equal to `3` so it will check if `arr[3*2]` will return something, it won't because there is no key 6 and it will return an error.

How can I do this with my idea?

Comment: You can use the get method:

arr.get(3*2, None)

Comment: @DmytroKuznetsov The default value is `None` only :-)

Comment: So basically what you're *really* trying to do is see if i*2 is less than the length of the list? I'm only asking because your question is strange. You don't need a dictionary for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note:** The item which you are referring to as `arr` is actually called `list` in Python. And the "hash table" is actually called as dictionary. So, I am going to refer the `arr` object as `dict_object`.

---

You can use `in` operator to check if the key is there in the dictionary or not,

```
if i * 2 in dict_object:
    print "!"
```

The `in` operator will return `True` if `i * 2` is a valid key in the dictionary, `False` otherwise.

---

There is one more way to do this. The dictionary objects have a function called [`get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), which accepts a default value to be returned if the key is not found in the dictionary. The default return value is `None`. You can use `None` as the sentinel value, like this

```
if dict_object.get(i * 2) is not None:
    # If the returned value is not None, then the key is present in the dictionary
    print "!"
```

---

There is another way to do this. When you access a key which is not there in the dictionary, you will get `KeyError`. You can except that, like this

```
for i in range(1, len(dict_object) + 1):
    try:
        if dict_object[i * 2]:
            print "!"
    except KeyError:
         # If value of `i * 2` is not in the dictionary, we will reach here
         pass
```

---

Apart from that, if the values you are storing in the dictionary are not used (in other words, if you are worried only about the keys), then you can use set instead of a dictionary, like this

```
numbers_set = {1, 14, 2, 4, 5, 11, 8, 10}    # Note {..}, not [..]
if i * 2 in numbers_set:
    print "!"
```

If you already have the list, then you can convert the list to a set, with [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set) function, like this

```
numbers_set = set([1, 14, 2, 4, 5, 11, 8, 10])
if i * 2 in numbers_set:
    print "!"
```

---

**PS:** There is a bug in your program. In Python, `range` function runs from the first parameter, till the last parameter value - 1. For example,

```
>>> range(1, 5)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> range(2, 10)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

the last value will not be included. So, you need to change the `range`'s parameters like this

```
for i in range(1, len(x) + 1):
```

Answer (score 0):

I honestly didn't understand what you intend to do, but you have some options.

for your `arr` dictionary (hash table)

```
>>> arr
{1: 'something', 2: 'something', 4: 'something', 5: 'something', 8: 'something', 10: 'something', 11: 'something', 14: 'something'}
>>> arr.keys()
[1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 14]
```

`arr.keys()` will return `key`s.

dictionaries also have `get(key, message)` method, if this dictionary have such key, this method will return its value, else `message`(default `None`).

```
>>> for i in range(len(arr)):
    print arr.get(i*2, "message")



something
something
message
something
something
message
something
message
```

or printing with keys, to be clearer

```
>>> for i in range(len(arr)):
    print i, arr.get(i*2)


0 None
1 something
2 something
3 None
4 something
5 something
6 None
7 something
```

or print message just for existing values

```
>>> for i in range(len(arr)):
    if i in arr.keys(): print arr.get(i*2)


something
something
something
something
```

or this.

```
>>> for i in range(len(arr)):
    if i in arr.keys(): print i,"--->", arr.get(i*2)


1 ---> something
2 ---> something
4 ---> something
5 ---> something
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is actually very confusing because in your first code snippet, you're iterating over the indices of your list, and in the second, you're creating a dictionary with the elements of the list as keys. It's impossible tell what you really want at this point, so here is an answer just in case you were really wanting to check if the *index* `i*2` was valid for any valid *index* `i`.

```
n = len(x)
y = [True]*sum(divmod(n, 2)) + [False]*(n//2)
```

This code snippet can efficiently create, and assign to `y`, a list which is a mapping from each valid index of your original list, `x`, to a boolean value indicating whether (`True`) or not (`False`) the index `i*2` is less than the length of the array.

Demo:

```
>>> x = [None] * 3
>>> n = len(x)
>>> y = [True]*sum(divmod(n, 2)) + [False]*(n//2)
>>> y
[True, True, False]
>>> x = [None] * 4
>>> n = len(x)
>>> y = [True]*sum(divmod(n, 2)) + [False]*(n//2)
>>> y
[True, True, False, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `get` method for dictionaries is what you want.

If you do `arr.get(2)` it will return the value you want, or `None` if there is no value.